# How to remove duplicated results and get a correct count instead of just 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create a view that shows each animal category, the type of animal as well as an accurate count of the total animals.

I am getting duplicate results, a count of 1 under totals and an inaccurate Category display.

Can anyone advise how to resolve these issues please

```
CREATE VIEW vw_PetsPerType
AS
    (
        SELECT   dbo.StockInfo.petQty, dbo.PetTypes.Category, dbo.Pets.Name
        FROM          dbo.StockInfo CROSS JOIN
                      dbo.PetTypes CROSS JOIN
                      dbo.Pets

    )

    (

        SELECT COUNT(Pets.Qty) as 'Total', (Pets.Name), PetTypes.Category
        FROM Pets, PetTypes
        GROUP BY PetTypes.Category, pets.Name

    )
GO
```

I expect the categories to match such as Dog-Mammal, Bird - Avian and Rabbit - Rodent and an accurate count of each.

I am getting Dog

```
Total   Animal  Category
1   Bird    Avians
1   Bird    Mammals
1   Bird    Rodent
1   Dog Avians
1   Dog Mammals
1   Dog Rodent
1   Rabbit  Avians
1   Rabbit  Mammals
1   Rabbit  Rodent
```

Comment: Have you already tried the SQL command `DISTINCT` in the select clausel, for removing doule entries?

Comment: "I expect the categories to match" this statement contradicts your use of a cross join, shouldn't you be using an inner join?

Comment: Thanks so much issue is resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using a CROSS JOIN which will join every row from one table  with every row from another table.  If you use a WHERE clause then you should eliminate the duplicates.

```
 WHERE pets.stockinfokey = StockInfo .stockinfokey AND
      pets.pettypekey = pettypes.pettypekey
```

Comment: Why not just explain how to do the correct join.  CROSS JOIN is clearly not what is needed